# solrj socket setSoTimeout() changes response time

Tags: java, sockets, solr, timeout, solrj

What would be the possible explanation for this ? We have a solr server and a java client which uses solrj. When we set the setSoTimeout to something below 5000 the response from the solr server arrives in 20-30 ms. However if we set it any higher or leave it at the default, the response time is 500-600 ms.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't think that the performance problem that you have is comming from socket timeout.

Other set of questions : 
- What is the request that you are executing ?
- how many doc have you got in your index ? what is the size of the index in MB?
- What is your server(s) configuration (CPU, RAM) ?
- Are you running on shards (solrcloud)? if yes how many shard/replicas?

References : 
- [solr wiki performance](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors)
- [solr wiki perfomance commons problems](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems)

Comment: The request is a simple *:* query, about 250 docs (it's a local test environment), 56.0 kb index size, the server is not sharded, and my parameters are cpu 2x2.66ghz and 4 gb ram. I doubt it's a server issue.. it's just a test on a local machine

Comment: Is the request using the field query or queryfilter (qf). Please try qf it s faster. Please give me the query I'll verify it.

Comment: It's not a specific query. In general when i do .setSoTimeout(5000) on the solrj SolrServer, it returns the response in 20-30 ms, otherwise if i dont set it in around 500 ms. With all queries e.g. q=*:*

Comment: hehe strange behaviour, there's a trick for sure! May I ask you to  [solrmeter](http://code.google.com/p/solrmeter) your solr in order to understand the bottleneck. Or if you want to, open your solr to the web and share it with me, I will trick it for you !